# Как сделать рандомное позиционирование кнопок при каждом запуске приложения?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qlayout, qpushbutton

Есть координаты под комментарием **`X`**, **`Y`**. Как сделать, чтобы они рандомно вставали за место установленных координат кнопок?

При каждом запуске по разному и чтобы не пересекались, не очень хочется делать большой код для нескольких сценариев координат.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QFont
from random import randint


class Game(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.start()

    def start(self):
        self.setFixedSize(300, 155)
        self.setWindowTitle("Number game")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("img/ico.png"))

#       X, Y
        x1 = 235
        x2 = 170

        y1 = 5
        y2 = 35
        y3 = 65
        y4 = 95
        y5 = 125


#       Numbers
        one = QPushButton("1", self)
        one.resize(55, 20)
        one.move(235, 5)

        two = QPushButton("2", self)
        two.resize(55, 20)
        two.move(170, 5)

        three = QPushButton("3", self)
        three.resize(55, 20)
        three.move(235, 35)

        four = QPushButton("4", self)
        four.resize(55, 20)
        four.move(170, 35)

        five = QPushButton("5", self)
        five.resize(55, 20)
        five.move(235, 65)

        six = QPushButton("6", self)
        six.resize(55, 20)
        six.move(170, 65)

        seven = QPushButton("7", self)
        seven.resize(55, 20)
        seven.move(235, 95)

        eight = QPushButton("8", self)
        eight.resize(55, 20)
        eight.move(170, 95)

        nine = QPushButton("9", self)
        nine.resize(55, 20)
        nine.move(235, 125)

        zero = QPushButton("0", self)
        zero.resize(55, 20)
        zero.move(170, 125)

#       random number
        rand = randint(0, 9)
        text = str(rand)

        num = QLabel(self)
        num.setFont(QFont("fonts/num.ttf", 35))
        num.setText(text)
        num.move(25, 15)

        self.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = QApplication(sys.argv)
    open = Game()
    exit(root.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Абсолютное позиционирование - это плохая идея. Научитесь применять layout-ы.

Ваша программы может выглядеть так и размет ее совсем не зависит от количества кнопок.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, QGridLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt
#from random import randint
from functools import partial



class PushButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, text, parent=None):
        super(PushButton, self).__init__(text, parent)

        self.setText(text)
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(60, 60))
        self.setMaximumSize(QSize(60, 60))


class Game(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.rows = 5
        self.columns = 2

        self.label = QLabel(self, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setFont(QFont("fonts/num.ttf", 35))

        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label, 1, 0, 5, 1)

        i = 1
        for row in range(1, self.rows+1): 
           for column in range(1, self.columns+1): 
                button = PushButton(
                            f'Button {i}', 
                            self
                )
                button.clicked.connect(partial(self.onClicked, i))
                layout.addWidget(button, row, column)
                i += 1

    def onClicked(self, i):
        self.label.setNum(i)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = QApplication(sys.argv)
    open = Game()
    open.resize(400, 300)
    open.show()
    sys.exit(root.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> Спасибо за совет, но возможно я не так выразился и вы меня не поняли, **нужно чтобы кнопки при каждом запуске были на разных местах**, например: кнопка 1 на месте кнопки 10 или 8 и так со всеми, абсолютно рандомно

Я вам, на всякий случай, сделал чтобы ни только при перезагрузке, но и при каждом нажатии на любую кнопку, все кнопки перестроятся. Если вам это не надо, уберите выделенный блочек из метода `onClicked`.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, QGridLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt
import random 
from functools import partial



class PushButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, text, parent=None):
        super(PushButton, self).__init__(text, parent)

        self.setText(text)
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(60, 60))
        self.setMaximumSize(QSize(60, 60))


class Game(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.rows = 5
        self.columns = 2

        self.label = QLabel(self, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setFont(QFont("fonts/num.ttf", 35))

        self.layout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label, 1, 0, 5, 1)

        self.createButton()

    def createButton(self):                                               # +++
        _list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
        random.shuffle(_list)
        i = 0
        for row in range(1, self.rows+1): 
           for column in range(1, self.columns+1): 
                button = PushButton(
                            f'Button {_list[i]}', 
                            self
                )
                button.clicked.connect(partial(self.onClicked, _list[i]))
                self.layout.addWidget(button, row, column)
                i += 1

    def onClicked(self, i):
        self.label.setNum(i)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        countLayout = self.layout.count()                             
        for it in range(countLayout - 1):             
            w = self.layout.itemAt(1).widget()
            self.layout.removeWidget(w)               
            w.hide()
        self.createButton()
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = QApplication(sys.argv)
    open = Game()
    open.resize(400, 300)
    open.show()
    sys.exit(root.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но возможно я не так выразился и вы меня не поняли, нужно чтобы кнопки при каждом запуске были на разных местах, например: кнопка 1 на месте кнопки 10 или 8 и так со всеми, абсолютно рандомно

Comment: @Zaard смотрите обновление