# gridlayout перекрывает окно pyqt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyqt

Продолжение вопроса по открытию окна в окне. Сделал я по быстрому форму, код есть и все почти что работает. Но проблема в том, что gridlayout перекрывает все кнопки на главном окне и нельзя никуда нажать. Но если grdilayout  перенести назад, то и второе окно будет открываться сзади, не поверх других окон. Что можно сделать? помогите!

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow_2(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(701, 166)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.dial = QtWidgets.QDial(self.centralwidget)
        self.dial.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(620, 60, 50, 64))
        self.dial.setObjectName("dial")
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 70, 18))
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        self.checkBox_2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 91, 18))
        self.checkBox_2.setObjectName("checkBox_2")
        self.checkBox_3 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 90, 91, 18))
        self.checkBox_3.setObjectName("checkBox_3")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "звук"))
        self.checkBox_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "уведомления"))
        self.checkBox_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "прогресс"))


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(700, 164)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(700, 164))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(700, 164))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 171, 61))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 60, 741, 21))
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 24)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 0, 531, 61))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 80, 171, 22))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-10, 0, 811, 171))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(81, 81, 81);")
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 701, 161))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.label.raise_()
        self.pushButton.raise_()
        self.progressBar.raise_()
        self.textEdit.raise_()
        self.comboBox.raise_()
        self.gridLayoutWidget.raise_()
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Открыть настройки"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(5, _translate("MainWindow", "6"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(6, _translate("MainWindow", "7"))

class ExampleApp2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow_2):               # Ui_MainWindow_2
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)



class ExampleApp1(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)

    def onClicked(self):
        self.exampleApp2 = ExampleApp2()
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.exampleApp2, 1, 0, 1, 2)


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp1()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пишите: `Продолжение вопроса по открытию окна в окне. Сделал я по быстрому форму,...`

Вы продолжаете вопрос, но почему-то основу берете с моего ответа, который не отмечен как правильный.

Я вам, по-моему, писал, что никогда не надо торопиться! Что значит `Сделал я по быстрому форму` ? **Вы плохо сделали формы и и не поместили виджеты в макеты.**

Еще раз вам говорю, что **вы не открываете окно в окне**, вы просто размещаете виджеты о окне используя `gridLayout`.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow_2(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(701, 166)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.dial = QtWidgets.QDial(self.centralwidget)
        self.dial.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(620, 60, 50, 64))
        self.dial.setObjectName("dial")

        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 70, 18))
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")

        self.checkBox_2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 91, 18))
        self.checkBox_2.setObjectName("checkBox_2")
        self.checkBox_3 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 90, 91, 18))
        self.checkBox_3.setObjectName("checkBox_3")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "звук"))
        self.checkBox_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "уведомления"))
        self.checkBox_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "прогресс"))


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(700, 364)
#        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(700, 164))
#        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(700, 164))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 171, 61))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 60, 741, 21))
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 24)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")

        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 0, 531, 61))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")

        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 80, 171, 22))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-10, 0, 811, 171))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(81, 81, 81);")
        self.label.setText("QLabel")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
#        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 701, 161))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")

        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")

        self.label.raise_()
        self.pushButton.raise_()
        self.progressBar.raise_()
        self.textEdit.raise_()
        self.comboBox.raise_()
        self.gridLayoutWidget.raise_()

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Открыть настройки"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(5, _translate("MainWindow", "6"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(6, _translate("MainWindow", "7"))

class ExampleApp2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow_2):               
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)



class ExampleApp1(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

# ++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton,  0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.progressBar, 1, 0)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit,    2, 0)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox,    3, 0)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label,       4, 0)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)

    def onClicked(self):
        self.exampleApp2 = ExampleApp2()
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.exampleApp2.dial,       5, 0)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.exampleApp2.checkBox,   6, 0)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.exampleApp2.checkBox_2, 7, 0)
# ++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp1()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @imapw_   посмотрите и попробуйте вот этот пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1079282/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba/1079297#1079297