# Как обновить контейнер в PyQt5?(Python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Я хотел научиться **обновлять контейнеры модуля PyQt5.**

Нашел метод `repaint()`, но, как я понял, ему необходимы координаты области, которую нужно обновить. Т.к. я не планировал использовать абсолютное позиционирование, мне это не подходит.

**Есть ли способ обновить конкретный контейнер?** Пожалуйста, подскажите, как это сделать **на примере нажатия на кнопку**(я хочу обновлять контейнер при нажатии на кнопку)?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.box)
        self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button')
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.click)
        self.button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button')
        self.box.addWidget(self.button1)
        self.box.addWidget(self.button2)

    def click(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: А что должно обновиться?

Comment: Я бы хотел хотя бы просто удалить все элементы контейнера, чтобы потом уже его заполнить

Comment: вы также можете посмотреть обновление в ответе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1079282/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba/1079297#1079297 - там при каждом нажатии на кнопку, все кнопки рандомно перестраиваются. A `repaint()` и `update()` это немного другое.

Comment: @S.Nick, Спасибо большое!

Comment: @MAXIM045  если у вас по ходу написание кода возникают проблемы, оформляйте новый вопрос, прикрепляйте пример. Напишите, что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается. Не надо обсуждать в комментариях вопросы по коду, который мы не видим.

Comment: Хорошо, я понял

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы удалить виджеты из контейнера (с установленным layout) надо делать так:

```
def click(self):
    count = self.layout().count()

    # Идем с конца
    for i in range(count-1, -1, -1):
      layoutItem = self.layout().itemAt(i)
      # Если лейаутИтем отвечает за виджет, то 
      # метод widget() вернет этот widget, иначе None
      w = layoutItem.widget()
      if w:
        self.layout().removeWidget(w)
        # Теперь надо убрать родителя из виджета 
        w.setParent(None)
        # И удалить сам виджет
        w.deleteLater()

      # Если же вам надо удалить вообще все элементы,
      # включая другие лейауты, то
      else:
        self.layout().removeItem(layoutItem)

      # Теперь ваш контейнер девственно чист
```

Если layout не установлен, а виджеты удалить надо, то вспоминаем, что все виджеты являются наследниками QObject, у которого, в свою очередь есть метод children(), тогда:

```
for child in self.children():
  # Например, проверим, что child это QWidget
  if isinstance(child, QWidget):
    child.setParent(None)           
    child.deleteLater()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что layout устанавливается методом `setLayout()`? Я делаю это в коде с примером, но если подставить ваш код, то возникнет ошибка, из-за того, что не находится `layout`. Скорее всего, я не понимаю чего-то в корне. `Layout` должен носить имя переменной, которая уже была в коде? Прошу прощения за такие глупые вопросы

Comment: @MAXIM045 Да, лейаут устанавливается методом setLayout. Опечатку исправил

Comment: Тогда, пожалуйста, подскажите, почему возникает ошибка >NameError: name 'layout' is not defined

Comment: @MAXIM045 потому что я вместо layoutItem.widget() написал layout.widget() и уже исправил эту опечатку в ответе

Comment: Даже если так, имя layout не находится с первой строчки `count = layout().count()`. И я не понимаю, откуда оно должно взяться:) Еще раз прошу прощения за глупые вопросы

Comment: @MAXIM045 так понятнее стало?

Comment: Понимаю, что я уже вам достаточно надоел. Ошибки теперь не возникают, но кнопка, к которой я привязал метод, ничего не делает. Т.е. кнопки остаются на окне. Честно говоря, я впервые вижу такие методы, не злитесь:)

Comment: @MAXIM045 да я не злюсь, но тогда надо дожить до понедельника, потому что мне негде это проверить. :)

Comment: Вы не против, если я задам новый вопрос на счет этого?

Comment: @MAXIM045 абсолютно не против, но давайте, если этот вопрос адресован именно мне, то в понедельник. А если вопрос общего характера, то тут есть зубры, которые на него быстрее меня ответят. Ошибку в ответе, я в любом случае исправлю, если она в нем есть

Comment: Вопрос будет адресован всем, кто захочет мне помочь, спасибо

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104485/discussion-between-alexander-chernin-and-maxim045).