# Как очистить контейнер PyQt5, который находится в другом контейнере?(Python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Вчера уже задавал здесь подобный вопрос и получил очень хороший ответ - мне нужно было очистить контейнер модуля PyQt5, [Как обновить контейнер в PyQt5?(Python3)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1082719/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b2-pyqt5python3). Т.к. я не знал принцип удаления виджетов из контейнера, думал, что иерархия контейнеров в окне не имеет никакого значения. Сейчас же у меня появилась необходимость поместить `QGridLayout` в `QHBoxLayout`, а в `QGridLayout` поместить кнопки, одна из которых будет очищать `QGridLayout` и добавлять новую кнопку в этот же `QGridLayout`. При этом я бы хотел сохранить остальные виджеты `QHBoxLayout` в покое. Чтобы было лучше понятно о чем говорю, нарисовал схему:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Очень старался сделать картинку максимально понятной, поэтому, если что-то получилось плохо, пожалуйста, сообщите мне, чтобы я мог учесть это в следующий раз.

**Пожалуйста, подскажите, есть ли возможность очистить контейнер, который находится внутри другого контейнера?** Или здесь уже нужно воспользоваться методами `repaint()` и `update()`?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.box1 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

        self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button1')
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.click)
        self.button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button2')
        self.button3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button3')
        self.button4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button4')
        self.button5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button5')

        self.box2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.box2.addWidget(self.button1, 0, 0)
        self.box2.addWidget(self.button2, 0, 1)
        self.box2.addWidget(self.button3, 1, 0)
        self.box2.addWidget(self.button4, 1, 1)

        self.box1.addLayout(self.box2)
        self.box1.addWidget(self.button5)
        self.setLayout(self.box1)

    def click(self):
        count = self.layout().count()
        for i in range(count-1, -1, -1):
            layoutItem = self.layout().itemAt(i)
            w = layoutItem.widget()
            if w:
                self.layout().removeWidget(w)
                w.setParent(None)
                w.deleteLater()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Сейчас этот код работает неправильно, т.к. теперь появился второй контейнер.

Comment: Вы можете менять видимость кнопок, не обязательно их удалять

Comment: А это будет работать с QLabel'ами, которые способны реагировать на клики мыши? Я планировал, что кнопок будет очень много, и нажатие на кнопку тоже образует очень много кнопок. Это не загрузит компьютер?:) Я думал, что удаление кнопки снизит ресурсозатратность

Comment: Не думаю, там только на память нагрузка будет. Кнопки не будут отрисовываться, поэтому не будет их обработки. Да и если смущает то, что они скрытые могут нагружать комп,то вызывайте у них не `hide()`, а `deleteLater()`, тогда они будут удалены

Comment: Еще одна проблема есть - я не знаю конличество и названия этих кнопок, они создаются в цикле, который обрабатывает базу данных. Получается, что у меня нет возможности обратиться к ним напрямую:(

Comment: Вы ведь их добавляете в layout, можете в этом же месте добавлять в свой список. Либо, вытащите кнопки из самого layout'а

Comment: В базе данных хранятся строки, разве я могу присвоить строке кнопку? Вытащить кнопки из loyaut'а значит вытащить их из `QGridLayout`? Просто хотелось сохранить их в контейнере

Comment: Во-первых, можете, например через словарь, где ключом будет строка, а значением кнопка. Во-вторых, раз есть место, где вы создаете кнопки и добавляете их в `QGridLayout`, то и сможете сделать список (`list`) и в него добавлять кнопки параллельно с добавлением на форму, а после обратиться к списку. В-третьих, лучше все-таки с `QGridLayout` работать и у него запросить содержимое, что и показано в моем ответе :)

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделал удаление из `QGridLayout` и добавление новой кнопки, что занимает все ячейки.

Добавление `New Button` выполняется через реализацию [addWidget(QWidget *widget, int fromRow, int fromColumn, int rowSpan, int columnSpan, Qt::Alignment alignment = Qt::Alignment())](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#addWidget-2), которая позволяет виджету заполнять несколько ячеек, подробнее:

> This version adds the given widget to the cell grid, spanning multiple
>   rows/columns. The cell will start at fromRow, fromColumn spanning
>   rowSpan rows and columnSpan columns. The widget will have the given
>   alignment. If rowSpan and/or columnSpan is -1, then the widget will
>   extend to the bottom and/or right edge, respectively.

Пример:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.box1 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

        self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button1')
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.click)
        self.button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button2')
        self.button3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button3')
        self.button4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button4')
        self.button5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button5')
        self.button6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('New Button')

        self.box2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.box2.addWidget(self.button1, 0, 0)
        self.box2.addWidget(self.button2, 0, 1)
        self.box2.addWidget(self.button3, 1, 0)
        self.box2.addWidget(self.button4, 1, 1)

        self.box1.addLayout(self.box2)
        self.box1.addWidget(self.button5)
        self.setLayout(self.box1)

    def click(self):
        for row in range(self.box2.rowCount()):
            for col in range(self.box2.columnCount()):
                w = self.box2.itemAtPosition(row, col).widget()
                w.deleteLater()

        self.box2.addWidget(self.button6, 0, 0, 1, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: здесь `QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter` - выравнивание по центру `QGridLayout`?

Comment: @finally, именно так. Подробнее в ссылке `addWidget` из ответа